# Different links depended on div-id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to add different links `href` depending on what the `id` of the `div` is.

The `a` elements are added via jQuery.

I have tried with

```
$id = document.getElementsByClassName("content-box")[0].id;
```

But then I don't know how to do the `switch-case`. I can't figure out how to retrieve all the ids.

Has anyone a better idea and could give me a hint on how to solve this?

```js
$link = "#";
$id = "";

switch($id){
 case "box-1":
 $link = "https://www.google.com/";
 break;
 
 case "box-2":
 $link = "https://stackoverflow.com/";
 break;
 
 case "box-3":
 $link = "https://www.apple.com/no/";
 break;
}

jQuery( '.container h2' ).after( 
'<a href="'+ $link +'" id="button-order">Read more</a>'
);
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.content-box {
  width: 30%;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div id="box-1" class="content-box">
    <h2>Title 1</h2>
  </div>
  
  <div id="box-2" class="content-box">
    <h2>Title 2</h2>
  </div>
  
  <div id="box-3" class="content-box">
    <h2>Title 3</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is your use case? You have box-1 etc. divs hardcoded. Why you need add <a> tag from code? If you have list of links and want to create wrappers to them shouldn't you just do some for-loop?

Comment: I am customising a code where I can't change the HTML by hardcoding. Thats why I have to do it via jQuery.

Comment: you just want to append <a> tag inside html is it?

Comment: @chandrashekharjoshi yes, that's right. inside the content-box-div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$id = document.getElementsByClassName("content-box")[0].id;
```

Only references the element at index `0` of the `HTMLCollection` returned by `.getElementsByClassList`.

You can use a iterate the `classList` within a `for` or `for..of` loop, to reference the current element at index N of the `HTMLCollection` and get the `id` of that element to pass to `switch`, substitute `.insertAdjacentHTML()` with `"beforeend"` set as first parameter and HTML string at second parameter

```js
for (let box of document.getElementsByClassName("content-box")) {

  let $link = "#";
  const $id = box.id;

  switch ($id) {
    case "box-1":
      $link = "https://www.google.com/";
      break;

    case "box-2":
      $link = "https://stackoverflow.com/";
      break;

    case "box-3":
      $link = "https://www.apple.com/no/";
      break;
  }

  box.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend"
  , '<a href="' + $link + '" id="button-order">Read more</a>');

}
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.content-box {
  width: 30%;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div id="box-1" class="content-box">
    <h2>Title 1</h2>
  </div>

  <div id="box-2" class="content-box">
    <h2>Title 2</h2>
  </div>

  <div id="box-3" class="content-box">
    <h2>Title 3</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Alternatively

```
for (let boxes = document.getElementsByClassName("content-box"), i = 0
    ; i < boxes.length; i++) {

  let $link = "#";
  const box = boxes[i];
  const $id = box.id;

  // same code at `for..of` loop
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$('.container').children('div').each(function(){` to populate the children from `.container>div` then use `switch($(this).attr('id')` to `switch` case between the child `id`:

```js
$link = "#";

$('.container').children('div').each(function() {
  switch ($(this).attr('id')) {
    case "box-1":
      $link = "https://www.google.com/";
      break;

    case "box-2":
      $link = "https://stackoverflow.com/";
      break;

    case "box-3":
      $link = "https://www.apple.com/no/";
      break;
  }
  $(this).children('h2').after(
    '<a href="' + $link + '" id="button-order">Read more</a>'
  );
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.content-box {
  width: 30%;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div id="box-1" class="content-box">
    <h2>Title 1</h2>
  </div>

  <div id="box-2" class="content-box">
    <h2>Title 2</h2>
  </div>

  <div id="box-3" class="content-box">
    <h2>Title 3</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```